# Getting instance of button/movieclip on it's click's handler

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

It used to happen in AS2.0 as follows :

```
my_Mc.onPress  = function()
{
   trace( this) 
}

//output : 
[my_Mc Movieclip]
```

However in AS3.0, i wonder how to achieve this

```
my_Mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, click) ;

function click(e:Event)
{
   trace( this ) ;  // output is the class instance, where the handler is being used 
// How to get the instance of my_Mc here ???? 
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `e.currentTarget` property.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget